# query for SPView does not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

my issue is how i could filter items on my SPView based on query:
i tried a query to make a filter based on user unfortunately no result on view, no change happen on the displayed items, i need your hepls please:

```
         string myquery = "<where><eq><fieldref name='Modifié par' LookupId='TRUE'/> 
                           <value type='int'>" + user.ID + "</value></eq></where>";

                SPView vv = list.Views[viewName];
                vv.Query = myquery;
                vv.DefaultView = true;
                vv.Hidden = false;
                vv.Update();
                list.Update();
                list.ParentWeb.Update();
```

Comment: A very handy tool to build CAML queries https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following with your SPQuery object:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='User'>Karine Bosch</Value></Eq></Where>
```

or

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer' /></Value></Eq>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use correct CAML syntax (lettering). And also `FieldRef Name` must contain the StaticName / Internal name of the column, not the display name. Also `Integer`, not `Int`:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name='Editor' LookupId='True'/> 
       <Value Type='Integer'>" + user.ID + "</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```